# Send SOAP request to NOAA

Tags: php, soap, soap-client, noaa

Kind of new to SOAP.  Trying to get weather data from NOAA website.  The first SOAP request shown below works, and returns the latitude and longitude.  The second SOAP request doesn't work.  I am obviously not sending the data correctly.  Can anyone help?  Thank you

```
<?php
    $wsdl = "http://graphical.weather.gov/xml/DWMLgen/wsdl/ndfdXML.wsdl";

    $client = new SoapClient($wsdl,array("trace"=>1,"exceptions"=>0));

    $rs = $client->LatLonListZipCode(98011);
    echo('<pre>'.print_r($rs,1).'</pre>');

    $par=array('latitude'=>39.0000,'longitude'=>-77.0000,'product'=>'time-series','startTime'=>'2004-04-27T12:00','endTime'=>'2004-04-30T12:00','Unit'=>'e','weatherParameters'=>'maxt = TRUE');

    $rs = $client->NDFDgen($par);
    echo('<pre>'.print_r($rs,1).'</pre>');
?>
```

Comment: In what way does the second request "not work?" Do you get an error message?

Comment: Yes, I get Notice: Array to string conversion in /var/www/html/testing/soap3.php on line 12, and then it returns a SoapFault Object.

Comment: What's on line 12? Is it `echo('<pre>'.print_r($rs,1).'</pre>');`? I'm just making sure this is your actual code, and not just a snippet.

Comment: Line 12 is $rs = $client->NDFDgen($par).  Playing around, and it looks like I don't want to pass it an array.

Comment: The following returns data: $rs = $client->NDFDgen(39.0000,-77.0000,'time-series','2012-08-31T12:00','2012-08-31T12:00','e','maxt = TRUE');  How would I have known that data should have been sent this way?

Comment: What does the WSDL definition say?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16042/discussion-between-user1032531-and-matt)

Comment: Can't - office firewall blocks chat.

Comment: I don't understand the question. Is this what you mean? <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ndf="http://graphical.weather.gov/xml/DWMLgen/wsdl/ndfdXML.wsdl">
<soapenv:Header/>
<soapenv:Body>
<ndf:NDFDgen soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
<latitude xsi:type="xsd:decimal">?</latitude>
<longitude xsi:type="xsd:decimal">?</longitude>
<product xsi:type="dwml:productType"

Comment: Yes. I'm not an expert in dealing with SOAP requests, but I'm pretty sure that parameters are passed the same as you would pass them to any PHP function.

Comment: At "http://www.restfulwebservices.net/wcf/StockQuoteService.svc?wsdl", an array is sent, and an object is returned.  $values = $client->GetStockQuote(array("request"=>"NCR"));

Answer (score 0):

`weatherParameters` is supposed to be an Associative Array.